# Rails simplify route condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently routing many pages to the same controller method:

```
type_regexp = Regexp.new([ :members, :businesses, :artists, :piercers, :models, :event_coverage].join('|'))
get ':type', to: 'users#group', constraints: { type: type_regexp }
```

Each one is a group name where the 'is_private' field is false. Is it possible to do something like this so I don't have to write out each group name:

```
type_regexp = Regexp.new(Group.where('SELECT name WHERE is_private = false').join('|'))
get ':type', to: 'users#group', constraints: { type: type_regexp }
```

Of course the above would never work, hopefully I got my point across. I want to be able to not worry when more groups are created and having to update the route file.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you wanting a slug?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your routes are setup when your application starts and not on every request. So now you wouldn't be able to do your example. You **SHOULD** do something like this in your controller. If nothing matches your regex you can just render a `404`.